# Question edited to show a different problem

Tags: support, edits, rollbacks

I answered a question yesterday with a perfectly valid answer (that more than likely solves the OP's problem); the question was:

> I have installed wamp server 2.2 I'm using windows 7 i am working on
>   php, recently i have installed windows 8.1, after that i have
>   installed wamp server.. but after installation it is showing the
>   following error "The program can't start because MVSCR110.dll is
>   missing from your computer."
>
> how to resolve this

*a low-quality question, but otherwise answerable*.

The OP edited their question to ask a *completely* different question:

> I have installed wamp server 2.2 I'm using windows 7 i am working on
>   php, recently i have installed windows 8.1, after that i have
>   installed wamp servep... wamp server icon is yellow, and it is not
>   showing online.. local host and phpmyadmin is also not working

The new question asked asks a completely different question to the original, how is this usually handled?

I had another user with full edit privileges roll-back the edit, but in the future how can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing this I was chatting to [BradleyDotNet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1783619/bradleydotnet) (who also rolled-back the question), who pointed me to [this question on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

The general consensus here is to leave the question & answers as-is if the answers are still valid for the new question being asked, and to roll-back the edit if they are not. In this case, it is also advisable to leave a comment for the OP to notify them that they should ask a different question, instead.

I ended up tackling this by having [BradleyDotNet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1783619/bradleydotnet) roll-back the invalid edit and then fixing the grammar & spelling issues of the question.

For reference, the question went from this:

> I have installed wamp server 2.2 I'm using windows 7 i am working on
>   php, recently i have installed windows 8.1, after that i have
>   installed wamp server.. but after installation it is showing the
>   following error "The program can't start because MVSCR110.dll is
>   missing from your computer."
>
> how to resolve this

to this:

[image]