# User accepted my answer, then completely changed the question and 'unaccepted'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, edits, specific-question, unaccepted-answer

I answered this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997660/why-wont-the-code-run/ and spent a fair amount of time on it. My answer was duly accepted.

However, today I looked at my rep and noticed that it had gone down (-15) and it was because my answer had been 'unaccepted'.

Fair enough, I thought. Maybe another answer was better. But looking at the question it seems that the user has completely changed the question. Of course my answer now doesn't answer the new question. Can anything be done about this?

Comment: This seems wrong, but there is nothing we can/should do but ask the user to revert what they did. I added a comment to that effect

Comment: I have reverted and commented about why. It looks like they *may* be trying to circumvent an question asking limit/ban by editing an existing question based on Martijn's comment.

Comment: Thanks guys! Hopefully he will accept my answer again...but I'm not holding my breath!

Comment: It's not acceptable to completely change a question once answers have been received (let alone actually *accepted*) - see e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285779/3001761, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291949/3001761. If this happens and you don't have the rep to roll the edit back yourself, raise a custom flag explaining what has happened.

Comment: Pick your battles. The question was already of questionable quality (_"This code doesn't work, debug it for me"_ combined with bad title, poor formatting and not responding to remarks in comments), so perhaps you should've tried to find a better question to answer.

Comment: see also: [how to deal with OP asking another questions after answering original question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275138/how-to-deal-with-op-asking-another-questions-after-answering-original-question)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The post is back in its original state, and the user has re-accepted the answer.

I've removed the comments on the post. Case closed, lets move on!